# Why uploaded jpg files are always 47bytes in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

Here is the `create` in `uploaded_file` controller. Only the portion of code related is presented here. The file for uploading is carried in `params[:uploaded_file][:file_for_upload]`:

```
def create
  ....
  uploaded_io = params[:uploaded_file][:file_for_upload]
  @uploaded_file.content_type = uploaded_io.content_type
  @uploaded_file.size_kb = BigDecimal(uploaded_io.size)/BigDecimal(1024)  #KB
  @uploaded_file.file_name = uploaded_io.original_filename
  @uploaded_file.file_extension = uploaded_io.original_filename.sub(/.+\./, '').downcase()
  File.open(Rails.root.join(@uploaded_file.storage_subdir, @uploaded_file.file_name), 'wb') do |file|
     file.write(uploaded_io)
  end
  .....
end
```

Here is the line of view for `file_for_upload`:

```
  <%= f.input :file_for_upload, as: :file, required: true %>
```

The uploaded process runs successfully. The file size recorded by `uploaded_io` is the actual size (xxxKB). The file saved is in `jpg` format and is in right subdirectory. But its size is only 47 bytes. A few more files are uploaded and they all end up 47 bytes no matter what its original sizes are. What's wrong with the `file.write` above?

Answer (score 0):

After added `read` to `upload_io`, file upload works fine:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join(@uploaded_file.storage_subdir, @uploaded_file.file_name), 'wb') do |file|
     file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```